# Upload image according to name in PHP

Tags: php, image

Suppose there are 2 same images in different names. I want to upload these images & put them in different folder. Suppose, img1.jpg & a-img1.jpg are the images. Now img1.jpg will go on "files/images/" location & a-img1.jpg will go on "files/a-images/" location. I've successfully  manage to upload images but it'll only go to one destination folder. This is my code,

```
    $upload_errors = 0;
    $images= $_FILES['img'];
    $img_id = get_new_image_id();
    $image_ok = true;
    $queries = array();
    $allowed_exts    = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'gif');
    foreach ($images['tmp_name'] as $key => $val ) {
        $fileName = $images['name'][$key];
        $fileSize = $images['size'][$key];
        $fileSize = round($fileSize/1024);
        $fileTemp = $images['tmp_name'][$key];
        $path_parts = pathinfo($fileName);
        $fileExt = $path_parts['extension'];
        $fileExt = strtolower($fileExt);
        if($fileSize > 2*1024){
            $image_ok = false;
        }
        if(!in_array($fileExt, $allowed_exts)){
            $image_ok = false;
        }
        if($image_ok){
            $upload_link = "files/images/".$img_id.".".$fileExt;
    $tupload_link = "files/a-images/".$img_id.".".$fileExt;

        move_uploaded_file($fileTemp, $upload_link);
        move_uploaded_file($fileTemp, $tupload_link);
        $img_id++;
        }else{
            $upload_errors++;
        }
```

Is there any way to identify an image file like "a-img1.jpg"? I need this help badly. Tnx in advance!

Comment: Does both images have the same name on form `img`?

Have different names for both images and then you will be able to identify that which image to upload in which folder.

Comment: @DeadMan, No. I've to use a single multiple upload button. Multiple images will be uploaded at the same time & my program needs to identify which one has "a" or not.

Comment: Check the `name` of the upload file to identify which location is suitable to it.

Comment: if you moved your uploaded file once, you cant do it again on the same file as it is already MOVED.

Comment: This is a bad idea because filename can have character "a" in it but if you want you can find the position of "a" in your filename by using `strpos` function. If you get it then upload it in different folder.

Read it more here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 1):

Since you already **moved** the file a second move from the same source won't work. Maybe you should **copy** the file the second time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to see if the string starts with "a-":

```
function startsWith($haystack, $needle){
    return strpos($haystack, $needle) === 0;
}
```

So you would do something like:

```
if(startsWith($img_id, "a-")){
    $upload_link = "files/a-images/".$img_id.".".$fileExt;
}else{
    $upload_link = "files/images/".$img_id.".".$fileExt;
}

move_uploaded_file($fileTemp, $upload_link);
```

Comment: what is `$haystack` & `$needle`?

Comment: They are the parameters for the function when you call it. So the $needle is what you are looking for in the $haystack. So when you do this: startsWith($img_id, "a-") It's looking for the needle "a-" in the haystack $img_id.